# I try to send my scores in my game to others via in-game mail

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I try to send my scores in my game to others via in-game mail, each user will send their own points with their own mail accounts, but they need to enable the "low security" application for google users to login. How can I make my game safer as Google wants instead of turning this feature on?

```
 MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.From = new MailAddress("" + mymail);
    mail.To.Add("" + tomail);
    mail.Subject = "" + name;

    mail.Body = name+ "'" + "in \n Tüm puanı :" + skor + "\n Son eriştiği puan :" + s3 + "\n Aylık puanı :" + sali + "\n Haftalık puanı :" + haftalık + "\n Gunluk puanı :" + gunluk;
    SmtpClient smtpServer = new SmtpClient(mailservisi);

    smtpServer.Port = 587;
    smtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("" + mymail,"" + password) as ICredentialsByHost;
    smtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
        delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        { return true; };
    smtpServer.Send(mail);
    Debug.Log("success");
```

Comment: Aside: Why is `"" + ` scattered all over your code?

Comment: man this is not the problem. I just leave my code as I want before finalizing it